# Xamarin.Forms Rectangle Causes Animation on WidthRequest Change

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a left-justified Rectangle living inside a Grid that gets resized based on a frequently-updated value. When the value changes, I change the WidthRequest for the rectangle.

On Android, the rectangle *immediately* jumps to the new width that I request. On iOS, it works the same way **if the width is decreasing**. However, on iOS, if the width increases the rectangle spends about ten frames redrawing & moving to the new width from the middle out. This ~10 frame animation that only happens on iOS when the width increases is the problem.

What is causing this animation and how to I stop it?

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Static art:Art.Icon1}" x:Name="NearbyIcon" IsVisible="True" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

            <Rectangle
                x:Name="BTBar"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="9,0,8,0"
                WidthRequest="120"
                HeightRequest="18"
                Stroke="Blue"
                Fill="Blue"
                RadiusX="1"
                RadiusY="1"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

```
        public void UpdateRSSI(double value)
        {
            BTBar.WidthRequest = (percent / 100.0d) * 103;
        }
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing us the code snippet to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I added some of the code. Then if you make a timer or something to trigger the update function on a set interval with a value [0,100], and make the value drop and go back up you should see the issue on iOS.

Comment: As a test, if you change column 0 to also be a fixed width, does that fix it? There's a slight chance that something buggy happens during layout, due to it having to compute where the column is. Second, have you verified that the width you request is never greater than the columnwidth? Third, would be good to verify that you are on the UI thread when you set WidthRequest.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @ToolmakerSteve.
I set column 0 to 30 pixels, since the pages where I show this give the entire meter 150 pixels (120+30). No dice.
The width request of the rectangle is always <120 because the value going into that function is between zero and 100.
I put the entirety of UpdateRSSI into Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread();

Unfortunately none of these have fixed the issue. I don't suspect it has anything to do with the auto sizing since the image is small and slower Android devices do it in one frame.

Comment: ok. Inside BeginInvokeOnMainThread, After setting WidthRequest, try `BTBar.ForceLayout();` OR maybe `this.ForceLayout();` OR `InvalidateLayout();`

Comment: Unfortunately neither ForceLayout() nor InvalidateLayout() stopped the unwanted animation.

Comment: I reproduced the issue ,the problem occurs both on decreasing and increasing width . This is happening because of the different rendering process on iOS/Android , and this could also be a potential issue , you can ask on github for better explanation : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.

Comment: Thank you @ColeX-MSFT.  If you reproduced the issue, maybe you also noticed that if you continuously shrink the rectangle (by maybe 1 pixel every 50ms) the rectangle will slip left as well.  For my use case that means it exits a frame that it lives inside.  I'm continuing to encounter an unreasonable amount of these Xamarin iOS "animations" that aren't on Android and aren't desired :(

Comment: Yes , the animation also perform unexpectedly when using a timer. Fell free to raise issue on github or open a support ticket here : https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/create?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Thank you.  It does appear there is a ticket opened for this issue now and there was already a related one opened December 2020 (7 months ago) so hopefully they fix this soon.  I feel like a fool for relying on Xamarin now because my app will no longer look professional and this delay is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until Microsoft and the Xamarin community fix this known bug, the solution for me is to switch to a BoxView.  It has almost all the same properties as a Rectangle but none of the animations/bugs that rectangles currently have.  It can be resized at will.  If you need a different border color, you can always draw a second BoxView over the first.